# Xcode cocos2D Deployment info Device Orientation Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Am using Xcode 8.1 with cocos2D V3 for developing a board game.

The game runs in the Landscape mode, which is set in the AppDelegate.m,

```
[startUpOptions setObject:CCScreenOrientationLandscape forKey:CCSetupScreenOrientation];
```

In the Deployment Info, (under 'General' tab), I had checked only the 'LandscapeLeft' and 'LandscapeRight' checkboxes. But while validating the Archive, it threw an error, : for iPad, all the orientations need to be checked.
Now the problem happens when I check the 'Portrait' checkbox. The game starts to run erroneously. An in-game timer does not run, (the update callback does not get called), a few animations do not run/get stuck. All this happens while the 'Portrait' checkbox is checked.

Any idea why this would be happening? Again, I might have overlooked / made a mistake somewhere? [(Please see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1SxS.png)

Help Much appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

Well strange as it may seem, the issue was this :

I had a small mistake in a function call in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[GameStats sharedGameObject] saveData];
}
```

while the method call should have been `applicationWillResignActive` ..

This spell mistake in the function call never threw a compiler error, and I had been testing on Simulators.

This solved the matter. Strange but clueless as to what went wrong under the hood ! !